# Facebook sharing debugger gives 404

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, dns, redirect

Can you please help me debug this! Whenever we are sharing content links from our website in facebook; its not working. Redirection to content works if I'm using desktop browser or directly opening the link in mobile browser. But from facebook in app browser I can see either its loading 404 page or the video doesn't play. What could be the reason behind this? Please check below link [from here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bioscopelive.com%2Fen%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Dqy9n5yYVXGO)

Answer (score 0):

Either redirect from http to https in general or change the og:image to https instead of http. If you enter the URL into the browser, you get redirected: http://www.bioscopelive.com/bundles/bongoweb/images/oglogo.jpg

You can also add `og:image:secure_url` as metatag with the https URL of the image.

Make sure that everything is public and not locked by gelocation or login. Facebook servers need to be able to reach the URLs.

Comment: Not only for images though ... If I enter https://www.bioscopelive.com/en/watch?v=qy9n5yYVXGO in my browser address bar, I get redirected to https://www.bioscopelive.com/en/login ... and according to the debug tool, the scraper gets redirected there as well.

Comment: yes; our contents are geo locked due to which it redirects user to login page if they are not logged in. So can this be the reason that as its taking to another link ; sharing isn't working?

Comment: it needs to be public, facebook needs to be able to reach it. if it´s locked somehow, it will never work.